# Why can we use MCT in the proof of Fubini's theorem (in Stein's book)?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

In Stein's *Real Analysis*, he uses six steps to prove Fubini's theorem.

First he uses $\mathcal F$ to denote the set of integrable funcyions satisfying the conclusions in the theorem:

> $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^{d_1}\times \mathbb R^{d_2})$ and
>
> 1. $f^y\in L^1(\mathbb R^{d_1})$ a.e. $y\in \mathbb R^{d_2}$.
> 2. $\int_{\mathbb R^{d_1}}f^y(x)\mathrm d x\in L^1(\mathbb R^{d_2})$.
> 3. $\int_{\mathbb R^{d_2}}\int_{\mathbb R^{d_1}}f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f.$

However, it confuses me that the definition of $\mathcal F$ is unclear, **because it's not trivial that if $f\in\mathcal F$ and $f=g$ a.e., then we have $g\in \mathcal F$.**

Besides, when proving that $\mathcal F$ is closed under operation of limits, he assumes that $\mathcal F\ni f_k\nearrow f$(the $\nearrow$ sign implies "$f_k\to f$ increasingly a.e." in the book) Then he applies MCT on $f_k^y$, **but I can't see why $f_k^y\nearrow f^y$ is true?**
(If we have $\lim f_k=f$ for every point in $\mathbb R^d$, then we can concludes that $f^y_k$ is integrable except a set $A(m(A)=0)$, then for all $y\in A^c$, $f^y_k\nearrow f^y$  is true. But here we must prove when $f_k\nearrow f$ , we also have $f^y_k\nearrow f^y$?)

I think **the two questions above** can both be solved if we can prove that any function supported on a set of measure zero is in $\mathcal F$, so we can drop the condition "a.e." to prove $f^y_k\to f^y$ increaingly everwhere. Hence it's sufficient to prove that if $m(E)=0$, then $m(E^y)=0$ a.e. $y\in \mathbb R^{d_2}$?
(But Stein proves this fact on step 4, which relies on the result we just want to prove.)

I don't know if I have missed something important or misunderstood the author, please point out any mistakes or give any hints.

Comment: @fwd  A set of measure zero in $\mathbb R^d$ not necessarily a zero measure set in $\mathbb R^{d_1}$, so here "a.e." has different meanings. For example, why $g^y\in  L^1$ for a.e. y?

Comment: But why the set of such $y$ is almost the $\mathbb R^{d_2}$?

Comment: Perhaps my explanation is confusing. I'll remove it and try to come up with a better one.